# Find a particular coefficient of Taylor series expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am given the following function:

$f(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+x^k).$

What is a fast way to find coefficient of $x^n$ in its Maclaurin series expansion i.e. $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$?

(I suspect this function is somehow used in number theory but I'm not quite familiar with the topic).

**Update:**

Following [the answer from MathOverview](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2906468) I can find the third order derivative:

$\begin{align}
D_x^{(3)}f(x) = & \sum \limits_{1 \le k_1 \le n} k_1(k_1-1)(k_1-2)x^{k_1-3} \prod \limits_{\substack{1 \le k_0 \le n \\ k_{0} \ne k_1}} (1+x^{k_0}) +
\\
+ & \sum \limits_{1 \le k_1 \le n} \sum \limits_{\substack{1 \le k_2 \le n \\ k_2 \ne k_1}} k_1 (k_1-1) k_2 x^{k_1+k_2-3} \prod \limits_{\substack{1 \le k_0 \le n \\ k_0 \ne k_1, k_2}} (1+x^{k_0}) + 
\\
+ & \sum \limits_{1 \le k_1 \le n} \sum \limits_{\substack{1 \le k_2 \le n \\ k_2 \ne k_1}} k_1 k_2 (k_1 + k_2 -2) x^{k_1+k_2-3} \prod \limits_{\substack{1 \le k_0 \le n \\ k_0 \ne k_1, k_2}} (1+x^{k_0}) + 
\\
+ & \sum \limits_{1 \le k_1 \le n} \sum \limits_{\substack{1 \le k_2 \le n \\ k_2 \ne k_1}} \sum \limits_{\substack{1 \le k_3 \le n \\ k_3 \ne k_1, k_2}} k_1 k_2 k_3 x^{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 - 3} \prod \limits_{\substack{1 \le k_0 \le n \\ k_0 \ne k_1, k_2, k_3}} (1+x^{k_0})
\end{align}$

(it is assumed here that $x^k = 0$ if $k < 0$).

Considering the first three derivatives, it looks like the $n$-th order derivative is going to be a sum of $2^{n-1}$ huge terms. Actually, since I'm interested in $f^{(n)}(0)$, I only need to find coefficients of $x^0$, and there are probably not that many of them. However, I still don't understand how to find them efficiently.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You will find you get comments and help if you show what you have done. You can edit your question to show your working. Even just a line or two will help.

Comment: These numbers are [partitions of $n$ into distinct parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts).

Comment: Fast is relative. Look at [OEIS sequence A000009](http://oeis.org/A000009) for some methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer. But an indication of the way to go to get your answer. The way is to make the successive derivatives until a pattern is realized and we use an inductive reasoning for the general case.
\begin{align}
D_{x} f(x) 
= &
D_{x}\left(\prod_{1\leq k_0\leq n}(1+x^{k_{0}})\right)
\\
= &
\sum_{1\leq k_{1}\leq n} k_{1}\cdot x^{k_{1}-1}\cdot\left(\prod_{\substack{1\leq k_{0}\leq n\\ k_{0}\neq k_{1}}}(1+x^{k_0})\right)
\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
D_x^{(2)} f(x) 
= &
D_x\left(
\sum_{1\leq k_{1}\leq n} 
        k_{1}\cdot x^{k_{1}-1}
        \cdot
        \left(
        \prod_{\substack{1\leq k_{0}\leq n\\ k_{0}\neq k_{1}}}
        (1+x^{k_0})
        \right)
    \right)
\\
= &
\sum_{1\leq k_{1}\leq n}
        D_x\left(
        k_{1}\cdot x^{k_{1}-1}
        \cdot
        \left(
        \prod_{\substack{1\leq k_{0}\leq n\\ k_{0}\neq k_{1}}}
        (1+x^{k_0})
        \right)
    \right)
\\
= &
\sum_{1\leq k_{1}\leq n}
        D_x
        \left(
        k_{1}\cdot x^{k_{1}-1}
        \right)
        \cdot
        \left(
        \prod_{\substack{1\leq k_{0}\leq n\\ k_{0}\neq k_{1}}}
        (1+x^{k_0})
        \right) 
\\
+ &
\sum_{1\leq k_{1}\leq n}
        \left(
        k_{1}\cdot x^{k_{1}-1}
        \right)
        \cdot
         D_x
        \left(
        \prod_{\substack{1\leq k_{0}\leq n\\ k_{0}\neq k_{1}}}
        (1+x^{k_0})
        \right) 
\\
= &
\sum_{1\leq k_{1}\leq n}
        k_{1}\cdot(k_{1}-1)\cdot x^{k_{1}-2}
        \left(
        \prod_{\substack{1\leq k_{0}\leq n\\ k_{0}\neq k_{1}}}
        (1+x^{k_0})
        \right) 
\\
+ &
\sum_{1\leq k_{1}\leq n}
\sum_{\substack{1\leq k_{2}\leq n \\ k_{2}\neq k_{1} }}
        k_{1}\cdot k_{2}\cdot
        x^{k_{1}+k_{2}-2}
        \cdot
        \left(
        \prod_{\substack{1\leq k_{0}\leq n\\ k_{0}\neq k_{1},k_{2}}}
        (1+x^{k_0})
        \right) 
\end{align}
And so on...

Comment: I've tried going in this direction but it seems like the number of terms grows exponentially with the order of derivative which makes it difficult for me to dicover an exact pattern. I've updated my question with what I was able to derive.